What is the difference between returning Select() and yield return?
Examples:
public IEnumerable<Class> ReturnClass()
{
    var list = ...;

    return list.Select(item =>
    {
        // if, else, etc

        return item;
    });
}

or
public IEnumerable<Class> ReturnClass()
{
    var list = ...;

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // if, else, etc

        yield return item;
    }
}

Are there differences in the generated code? Performance? Etc
I only found one question on stackoverflow about this subject, but it raised more questions than it answered questions

Second should be faster, because Select has to call the function for each element, i.e. yield return func(item);, where func just passes the value through

Why not just return list; ? No need to .Select or a loop to yield return.

@dr.null The use case I had thought of was something more complex instead of a simple return

I edited it to make the intention clearer

In a sample where you already have a list it does not matter you won't understand the difference as it does not show a real world problem.  The difference start when the ReturnClass method needs to calculate what to return next. Then yield gets interesting and better performing. Because if the caller decides to no longer enumerate on the iterator returned by ReturnClass() nothing will be further calculated in ReturnClass() so a complete List has never existed and does not need to be created.

Without yield you would need to create and precalculate the complete list even when the caller will only look at the first element and stops iterating.

@Ralf only if ToList() is called within the method which I do not see here. Otherwise the Select would still be lazily-evaluated.

@DStanley my answer was when he don't have a list already ignoring his example code. As that does not make sense to compare select and yield this way as you never would do it in the shown way. Either return list directly or calculate what should be returned without a list just with a yield.

@Ralf In both ways, would the list be evaluated in a lazy way? If so, in my view there wouldn't be much difference between the ways to return something, which leaves me more confused about which would be the most recommended

Both have there own right in the right circumstance. There is no one is better then the other. Let me try to construct a sample that is more telling.

This is simple enough to run a Benchmark and know it for sure ;)

"I only found one question on stackoverflow about this subject, but it raised more questions than it answered questions" And what question was that?  What questions did it raise for you?  What was the explanation you were given, and what about it did you not understand? What did you learn when you tested your two implementations?  Did you see any differences (either in performance or behavior)?

@Servy The questions are: Which would be more recommended? What's the difference between the two? If they do the same thing, which one to use?

@Luiz And what was the question you found on the topic?  How did it fail to answer the question?  Why do you need someone to tell you which of two equivalent thing to use? If they're the same, then they're the same.  And again, what happened when you tried them?

@Servy I managed to understand both from Dmitry Bychenko's answer, thanks anyway

The main differences is that yield return creates state machine and thus executes lazily. Lazy execution can be problematic in case of validation, let me show some toy example:
// State Machine, Lazy execution
public IEnumerable<int> ReturnClassLazy(int count)
{
    // Validation (will be called lazily)
    if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, count);

    foreach (var item in list) 
        yield return item * item;
}

// Eager execution
public IEnumerable<int> ReturnClassEager(int count)
{
    // Validation (will be called eagerly)
    if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));

    var list = Enumerable.Range(1, count);

    return list.Select(item => item * item);
}

In case of eager version (when we return Select(...)), the method will be executed immediately (note, that validation will be called):
// ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown (invalid count argument, -1)
var result = ReturnClassEager(-1);

while in case of lazy call (yield return version)
// Nothing happens (even if count argument -1 is invalid)
var result = ReturnClassLazy(-1);

... /* imagine 10000 lines of code here */

// Only here (when we materialize) 
// the exception is thrown due to invalid count argument -1
int sum = result.Sum();

Usually, we want validation exception be thrown as early as possible, that's why eager version is easier to maintain.

Does .Select() have an eager evaluation? I thought it was lazy, as far as I know all methods in the IEnumerable interface are lazy

@Luiz: Linq itself is lazy (if there's a exception within Select you'll see the exception on the materialization), you are quite right. But ReturnClassEager is eager (note that validation is not within Linq Select) when entire ReturnClassLazy is lazy

Ah, now I understand, thank you

One question, if there is no validation, are both executed lazily in this case? One question, if there is no validation, are both executed lazily in this case? The difference would be that the version with .Select() would not create the state machine, and with yield it would, but both would execute in a lazy way

@Luiz: There are two popular constructions - yield return and async which are turned into state machines and executed lazily (Linq Select uses yield return and thus lazy). All the rest are eager. In your case 1st sample will be eager (except for Linq) when 2nd will be lazy. You don't have validation (audit, logging, precomputed results check etc.) so lazy / eager difference doesn't play greate role for you. However, input parameters validation is a quite frequent requirement that's why I've written my answer.

I got it, thanks

The deferred execution behavior of a method that includes a yield statement is documented by Microsoft here.

Maybe a more telling sample (but not answering the Select() part as i see it as irrelevant detail) that shows the difference when yield is used. ReturnClassYield() will only call as many Random.Next's until one evaluates to 3 so you may be lucky todo less then 5 calls to Random. In ReturnClass() all 5 calls to Random will be done even if an early one evaluates to 3. So ReturnClassYield() might be faster because it has potentially todo less calculation. In your own Sample everything depends on what list is if its itself a lazy evaluated Enumerable the behavior changes but as you didn't show what list is i assume its something already evaluated.
void Main()
{
    foreach (var value in ReturnClassYield())
    {
        if (value == 3)
          break;
    }

    foreach (var value in ReturnClass())
    {
        if (value == 3)
            break;
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> ReturnClassYield()
{
    yield return Random.Shared.Next(0,10);
    yield return Random.Shared.Next(0,10);
    yield return Random.Shared.Next(0,10);
    yield return Random.Shared.Next(0,10);
    yield return Random.Shared.Next(0,10);
}

public IEnumerable<int> ReturnClass()
{
    return [
        Random.Shared.Next(0,10),
        Random.Shared.Next(0,10),
        Random.Shared.Next(0,10),
        Random.Shared.Next(0,10),
        Random.Shared.Next(0,10),
    ];
}

